# Is it possible to re-sync table with logical replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Let's imagine that someone executed the command

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl1;
```

on logical replica.

How will it be correct to synchronize only one table again?

I use PostgreSQL 14.

Comment: I doubt this is possible in principle, a table can have foreign keys. A separate table update will bring the database into a transactionally inconsistent state.

Comment: Assuming that foreign keys are not a problem, I think the only option is to remove and re-add the table to the publication and then refresh the subscription.